# Does Meteor Enforce CamelCase for Template Names?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, spacebars

So I've a route called 'find_project' as follows:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route("/find_project");
}
```

And my template is as:

```
<template name="find_project">
  <h1>Find project page</h1>
</template>
```

**Obviously, one would expect the template to work, right? NO!**

```
Couldn't find a template named "FindProject" or "findProject". Are you sure you defined it?
```

Now I camel-case the template name like so:

```
<template name="findProject">
  <h1>Find project page</h1>
</template>
```

And magically, it started working.

**Does Meteor enforce camel casing in template names?**

Answer (score 2):

Meteor does not enforce camel-cased names, the problem you're facing comes from `iron:router` trying to guess the template name from the route path, using a camel-cased heuristic by default.

If you prefer underscore based names, rewrite your routing function as :

```
Router.route("/find_project",{
  template:"find_project"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Router.setTemplateNameConverter(_.identity);
```

from: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1064